# Remove disabled Input field

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, wordpress, disabled-input

I've bought a Wordpress theme, but it collides with one of my essential plugins.

This is the page: https://inspirebyloui.dk/checkout/ (you need to add a product to the basked to see the issue. Then see the button below "GLS Pakkeshop" and "DAO Pakkeshop".)

I've figured out that I need to remove the disabled parameter in the input field.

```
<input disabled type="button" onclick="getShopList('gls', jQuery('#Pakkelabels_zipcode_field').val());" id="pakkelabels_find_shop_btn" name="pakkelabel_find_shop" class="button alt" value="Find nærmeste udleveringssted">
```

I've managed to remove it with JS, with the following code

```
document.getElementById("pakkelabels_find_shop_btn").disabled = false;
```

However, it seems like this input field is loaded via Ajax, which is why the above JS code works fine in the console, but when I activate the input field again, it's disabled again.

Anyone knows how to deal with this?

BR
Martin

Comment: You have jQuery. You can do something like `$("#pakkelabel-modal").on("click"," [name=pakkelabel_find_shop]",function() { $(this).removeAttr("disabled")})`

Comment: Thanks!

However, the button should be active when the page is loaded. Not on click.

Comment: you have a JavaScript error from Stripe. try to desactivate the Stripe plugin to see it the problem disapears.

Comment: Thanks! That worked! Great great great!

Comment: Feel free to delete the question which is only useful to you

Answer (score 0):

Hej Martin,

You could use jQuery and do something like this:

```
jQuery("#Pakkelabels_zipcode_field").on("input",function(){
document.getElementById("pakkelabels_find_shop_btn").disabled = false;
});
```

This would activate the button after the user has input a postal code.

Hope that helps.

God dag!

Comment: Hi Sammy,Thanks for your response. Didn't try the solution you propose, as it was another Paymeny gateaway that was causing this issue.